# c++ Calling multiple methods with frequent interval

Tags: c++, c++17

My application is related to monitoring features. The requirement is to monitor lot of feature at same time.
I have separate methods defined for each feature.

Eg:

```
void feature1(std::string &output)
{
    // logic to generate/fetch/calculate value
    // and then copy the value to output variable
}

void feature2(std::string &output)
{
}

void feature3(std::string &output)
{
}

.
.
.
.

void feature100(std::string &output)
{
}
```

I am calling these methods in another method using multiple if else condition
eg:

```
void getValue(std::string featureName, std::string &output)
{
    if(featureName.compare("f1") == 0)
    {
        feature1(output);
    }
    else if(featureName.compare("f2") == 0)
    {
        feature2(output);
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    else if(featureName.compare("f100") == 0)
    {
        feature100(output);
    }
    
}
```

my requirement is to log all or user specified features(can be multiple) value in a csv file with some specific interval. The minimum interval is 2 ms. Assume if user wants to log 50 features with 2ms interval then my log file should generate 500  * 50 entries in a minute.

```
std::ofstream logFile("log.csv");
std::vector<std::string> featureList{"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4" …….. "f50"};

while(stopRequested)
{
    for(auto iter : featureList)
    {
        std::string output{};
        getValue(iter, output);
        logFile <<  output << ",";
    }
    logFile << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
}
```

since the methods called sequentially, I am not getting expected number of entries in a specified interval.  I thought of using threads to call getValue method but this will create 50 threads in 2ms. Not sure using thread will be a right approach.
What will be best approach to deal this requirement. I am supposed to use c++17 but I am new to it.

Comment: Side note: When I'm lazy and don't need performance, writing something with a large set of what you call features, or expect to have a large set, I'll use `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<common_prototype>>` and eliminate the need for the `if`s and `else if`s.

Comment: Side note: A modern compiler will perform `std::string getValue(std::string featureName)` in the same amount of effort as `void getValue(std::string featureName, std::string &output)` thanks to copy elision and you get to write simpler code: `logFile <<   getValue(iter);<< ",";`

Comment: Use one thread for calling your `getValue` sequentially, and one thread for dealing with writing to the logfile. You could do a lock-free version to impact the performance of the `getValue` as little as possible.

Comment: Correction to code 2 comments above: `logFile << getValue(iter)<< ",";`

Answer (score 1):

In order to account for the time taken by the loop body you can calculate the time of the new loop iteration before all the calculations and then use `sleep_until`:

```cpp
while(!stopRequested)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    auto next_iter_time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 2ms;

    for(auto iter : featureList)
    {
        std::string output{};
        getValue(iter, output);
        logFile <<  output << ",";
    }
    logFile << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_iter_time_point);
}
```

Additional remarks:

- I changed the loop condition because I think you forgot `!`
- You don't have to use the `compare` member function on a `string`. You can just use the `==` operator.
- As @user4581301 said in the comments, the sleep period will not be accurate and reliable. This is due to many reasons such as the limited resolution of the system clock and context switches that could forcefully make your sleep thread, especially when the system is busy.

To further improve the performance of `get_value` you could use a function pointer array to avoid costly branches:

```cpp
void getValue(const std::string& featureName, std::string &output)
{
    using feature_func_t = decltype(feature1)*;
    constexpr feature_func_t feature_funcs[]{
        feature1,
        feature2,
        /*...,*/
        feature100
    };
    const int feature_func_idx = atoi(featureName.c_str() + 1) - 1;
    assert(feature_func_idx >= 0 && feature_func_idx < 100);
    feature_funcs[feature_func_idx](output);
}
```

Comment: Also note that on a typical desktop PC you may not be able to get a reliable 2ms tick. `chrono` may resolve to nanoseconds, but it can only provide what the underlying system deigns to give it.