# C++ calling a method in specified interval without sleep

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to execute multiple methods with specified interval(1 millisecond). Is there any way to call the methods in a loop without **sleep** because I am not getting 1000 entries in a log file for a second
Currently I have implemented using sleep. Data collection also might take little time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <csignal>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <atomic>

volatile std::sig_atomic_t gStatus{};

void signalHandler(int sig) {
    gStatus = sig;
}

void feature1(std::string &output) { output = "feature1"; }
void feature2(std::string &output) { output = "feature2"; }
void feature3(std::string &output) { output = "feature3"; }
void feature4(std::string &output) { output = "feature4"; }
void feature5(std::string &output) { output = "feature5"; }
void feature6(std::string &output) { output = "feature6"; }

void processInfoRequest(std::string logFile, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string &value)>> methodMap)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(logFile);

    std::uint64_t prevTime = 0, curTime = 0, diffTime = 0, tmpTime = 0, scheduleTime = 0, pollPeriod = 1;

    prevTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    while (gStatus != SIGINT)
    {
        prevTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        prevTime = prevTime - scheduleTime;

        **//get value**
        auto timenow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
        ofs << ctime(&timenow);

        for(auto it : methodMap)
        {
            std::string output;
            it.second(output);
            ofs << output << ",";
        }

        ofs << "\n";        

        curTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        diffTime = curTime - prevTime;

        if (diffTime < pollPeriod)
        {
            diffTime = pollPeriod - diffTime;
            curTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            std::uint64_t i = 0;
            std::uint64_t n = diffTime / 10;
            std::uint64_t remainingMs = diffTime % 10;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(remainingMs));

            tmpTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            scheduleTime = tmpTime - (curTime + diffTime);
        }
        else
        {
            scheduleTime = 0;
        }

    }

    ofs.close();
}


int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    std::string output;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string &value)>> methodMap = {
        {"f1", feature1},
        {"f2", feature2},
        {"f3", feature3},
        {"f4", feature4},
        {"f5", feature5},
        {"f6", feature6}
    };
    
    std::thread th1 = std::thread(processInfoRequest, "threadlog.csv", methodMap);

    if (th1.joinable())
        th1.join();
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think using sleeps is a problem?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza The sleep period will not be accurate and reliable. This is due to many reasons such as the limited resolution of the system clock and context switches that could forcefully make your sleep thread, especially when the system is busy. Also observed I am not getting expected number of entries

Comment: Well, you should be checking delta time until next action every time you wake up.  And you shouldnpt just check delta since end of last event.

Comment: This question seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592545/c-calling-multiple-methods-with-frequent-interval